# Whats the max size of indexed db on IE11 on windows 8.1 and windows 10?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, indexeddb

For indexed db for IE11, I know for windows 8.1, it shows the limit (limit as in before it requests user permission to use more), as 10mb by default. Also according to this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
edge removes this limit. But on IE11 on windows 10, what is the default limit? When I check the settings, it doesn't even seem to have an option to set a limit.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have mentioned os versions, so can't myself. Why don't you try to fill it up and get the default limit experimentally?..